# How do I get the height of a figure in LaTeX

Tags: floats

I have some LaTeX code

```
\begin{figure}
    ABC
    \caption{def}
\end{figure}
```

And I would like to be able to find its height in a `pdf` output. The method outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2939450/get-height-on-a-block-of-latex-output) doesn't work, yielding the error:

```
! LaTeX Error: Not in outer par mode.
```

I considered the idea of using `\write18` and somehow measuring the size of the figure by itself using pixel-grabbing tricks, but if the document had a globally changed caption size, that would mess things up.

I was wondering if there was a valid way to do this.

Comment: you want to get the height of `ABC` or the whole figure including caption

Comment: The whole figure. Like how much space the whole thing uses on the page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{capt-of}

\newsavebox\mybox
\begin{document}    
\sbox\mybox{\parbox[b]{\textwidth}{ABC\captionof{figure}{bla bla}}}
\the\ht\mybox
\end{document}
```

Here is another solution:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\the\pagetotal

\begin{figure}[h]
    ABC
    \caption{def}
\end{figure}

\the\pagetotal

\end{document}
```

---

**Update**
In this example we try to reproduce float position by hand in the first page and in seconde page we let latex does the job.

**Note:** as one can see for top position there is no problem. Reproducing bottom position is difficult (if not impossible?)
[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{capt-of}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newsavebox\mybox
\newcommand\myfigure[1][(Manually)]{\rule{5cm}{1cm}\captionof{figure}{My figure #1}}

\begin{document}                           
\sbox\mybox{\parbox[b]{\linewidth}{\myfigure
                             \boxmaxdepth \maxdepth
                             \vbox{}
                             \vskip -\floatsep
                             \topfigrule
                             \vskip \textfloatsep}} 

\noindent\parbox[b]{\linewidth}{\myfigure
                             \boxmaxdepth \maxdepth
                             \vbox{}
                             \vskip -\floatsep
                             \topfigrule
                             \vskip \textfloatsep}
\the\ht\mybox****\lipsum[3]

\sbox\mybox{\parbox[b]{\textwidth}{\myfigure}}
\noindent\parbox[b]{\textwidth}{\myfigure}
Height without any vspace:\the\ht\mybox****\lipsum[3-4]

bla bla

this is difficult, see value of the height in next page


\sbox\mybox{\parbox[b]{\linewidth}{\vskip \textfloatsep
                             \botfigrule
                             \vbox{}
                             \vskip -\floatsep
                             \myfigure}}
\noindent\parbox[b]{\linewidth}{\vskip \textfloatsep
                             \botfigrule
                             \vbox{}
                             \vskip -\floatsep
                             \myfigure}
\newpage\the\ht\mybox****\lipsum[3]
\begin{figure}[t]
\myfigure[(\LaTeX)]
\end{figure}
\lipsum[3-4]
\begin{figure}[b]
\myfigure[(\LaTeX)]
\end{figure}
\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Does this include the depth of of possible descenders in the caption like `g` or `p` etc.?

Comment: I'll have to test this out with more complex examples, but it seems to work with `\includegraphics` and multi-line comments. I'll have to test a little more before accepting, but I'll +1.

@ChristianHupfer for my purposes, I can be a few pixels off. I just can't be an entire caption off.

Comment: I think this is not so good (there is `\textfloatsep` not considered here) I will see later.

Comment: Also, @touhami, is there anything other than `caption` -> `captionof` and disabling `label` I need to do to automate this process?

Comment: @touhami. The new solution doesn't work if the figure is placed somewhere other than the current location (I'm trying to extract figures sizes from existing documents)

Answer (score 5):

The figure is stored in a box so you can measure it (you'd need to work a bit harder for `h` floats as they may be used before the reporting happens if done after  the environment as here)

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}


\begin{figure}
    ABC
    \caption{def}
\xdef\thisfloat{\the\csname @currbox\endcsname}%
\end{figure}
\typeout{%
** This float + caption has height + depth:^^J**
\the\dimexpr\ht\thisfloat+\dp\thisfloat\relax}

\end{document}
```

Produces a log of

```
** This float + caption has height + depth:
** 30.77776pt
```

or collected up until the end:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}


\begin{figure}
    ABC
    \caption{def\label{z}}
\xdef\thisfloat{\the\csname @currbox\endcsname}%
\end{figure}
\edef\tmp{\noexpand\AtEndDocument{%
\noexpand\foo{z}{\the\dimexpr\ht\thisfloat+\dp\thisfloat\relax}}}%
\tmp

aaaa

\begin{figure}
    ABC\\
XYZ
    \caption{def\label{z2}}
\xdef\thisfloat{\the\csname @currbox\endcsname}%
\end{figure}
\edef\tmp{\noexpand\AtEndDocument{%
\noexpand\foo{z2}{\the\dimexpr\ht\thisfloat+\dp\thisfloat\relax}}}%
\tmp


aaaa


\def\foo#1#2{% whatever you want to do with the data
\typeout{**^^J%
** This float (#1) + caption has height + depth: #2^^J**
}}

\end{document}
```

---

```
**
** This float (z) + caption has height + depth: 30.77776pt
** 
**
** This float (z2) + caption has height + depth: 42.77776pt
**
```

Comment: Is there a way to put that code in uniquely named variables so that it can be placed `\AtEndDocument`? I'm currently using something to trap labels so I can use labels as IDs.

Comment: @k_g updated answer

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear, but I was implying that using `\AtEndDocument` could be used to solve the `h` problem because the reporting would be done at the end of the document.